# Has Microsoft lowered its Windows 11 eligibility criteria?

Tags: windows, windows-11

My main home PC is running Windows 10, and is about 6 years old now. Though it was of a very high specification when new, built for video editing and rendering, and still no slouch.

As such it lacked the TPM2 and processor generation required to qualify for 11 on release.

However... Yesterday (28th Feb 2023) on boot it gave me a full screen saying "Now Unlocked: You're eligible for a free upgrade to Windows 11"

I didn't proceed and decided to stick with 10 for now as I needed to submit a tax return in the 3 hours between then and midnight.. and I'm fine with 10.

Comment: As a side note - are you _sure_ you don't have TPM 2.0? On many mainboards from six years ago, it was already present, but disabled by default.

Comment: I just got the notification like yours while my PC was not met the requirement specifically TPM 2.0 was disabled. However, I could upgrade to Windows 11 successfully without configuring anything. Now that I know it was a mistake, I don't know if I should downgrade or keep this. My machine is working fine though.

Comment: @Luaan A 6 years old computer means a CPU from 2017. That most likely means a 7th Gen Intel CPU or first Gen Ryzen. AFAIK neither are on the official list of supported processors for Windows 11.

Comment: @Luaan - Yes I checked, it's a Gigabyte board, was mid-high range at the time but doesnt have tpm2. The CPU is a 7th gen i7.

Comment: I think there;s a few reports of them offering updates incorrectly so be careful about that

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is an ongoing thing, as described in the article
[Microsoft mistakenly offered Windows 11 upgrades to users with unsupported PCs](https://www.engadget.com/microsoft-mistakenly-offered-windows-11-upgrades-to-users-with-unsupported-pcs-225303542.html):

> “Some hardware ineligible Windows 10 and Windows 11, version 21H2
> devices were offered an inaccurate upgrade to Windows 11,” Microsoft
> states in a [support
> document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/status-windows-11-21H2#windows-11-upgrades-were-offered-to-ineligible-devices)
> spotted by [The
> Verge](https://www.theverge.com/2023/2/25/23614723/microsoft-windows-11-unsupported-pcs-update-accident).
> “These ineligible devices did not meet the minimum requirements to run
> Windows 11. Devices that experienced this issue were not able to
> complete the upgrade installation process.” Microsoft adds it resolved
> the issue the same day it was detected.

You should locate and use the "keep Windows 10" link, although it gets
harder to spot with succeeding versions of the announcement.
If you click the "Get it" button, the installation
will just fail.

If you can't spot this link in the message, see
[Windows 10: Uncovering the Deception of the Windows 11 Upgrade Screen](https://www.ghacks.net/2023/02/01/windows-10-now-unlocked-windows-11-upgrade-screen-is-a-deceptive-design-pattern/)
for advice.

Answer (score -1):

There's a way to bypass the TPM 2.0 requirements, as [explained in this article](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/bypass-windows-11-tpm-requirement). So you can completely ignore whatever official requirements are set by Microsoft and use Windows 11 at your pleasure. A quick summary of how it's done:

> 1. Navigate to the Skip_TPM_Check_on_Dynamic_Update.cmd source code on [AveYo's Media Creation Tool Github](https://github.com/AveYo/MediaCreationTool.bat/blob/main/bypass11/Skip_TPM_Check_on_Dynamic_Update.cmd).
> 2. Click the "Copy raw contents" button in the upper right corner of the code box.
> 3. Create a new file on your desktop and name it skip_tpm_check.cmd. Make sure that you are able to view file extensions and the file
>    extension is really .cmd, not .txt or else it won't run.
> 4. Open skip_tpm.cmd for editing, using notepad or another text editor.
> 5. Paste in the code you copied from github.
> 6. Save and run the skip_tpm.cmd file.
> 7. Click Yes if prompted by User Account Control.
>
> You will now see a message saying "Skip TPM on Dynamic Update" has
> been installed. If you run the program again, it will disable the
> utility. Windows Update should now be able to upgrade you from Windows
> 10 to 11.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144323/discussion-on-answer-by-jonathanreez-has-microsoft-lowered-its-windows-11-eligib); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.